# Realex payment Http response not triggering iFrame to go to right URL

Tags: iframe, payment-gateway, peoplesoft

We are using Realex HPP mode in an iframe inside a Peoplesoft Campus Solutions page(Tools Release=8.54.28 and Campus Solutions= 9.00.00.000)

The issue we are finding when using the test sandbox environment seem to be that HTTP response header is not making the iFrame to go to the url specified

We already tried firewall rules
We tried recommendation to remove the MERCHANT_URL and use the two fields specified in [Realex HPP iFrame / WebView Optimisation](https://developer.realexpayments.com/#!/hpp/customization/hpp-iframe-webview-optimization) 
added fields HPP_POST_DIMENSIONS and HPP_POST_DIMENSIONS

but even that the browser seem to have back an HTTP response back it is not triggering the iframe in the browser to go to the URL specified.

Just to take out the Peoplesoft Adapters out of the equation we tried with another test payment vendor and it worked.

Can anybody confirm that [Realex test sandbox](https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/) is providing the right HTTP Headers in the response?
When comparing the responses to others it seem to be missing the "LOCATION Header"

Thanks at front for any help on this topic.

Jerson

Comment: did you try reaching out to them?

Comment: Hi,
Yes we did contact them but no progress. During a call with them it was determined there was an HTTP response back but for some reason it did not triggered the code to continue execution. When comparing with other vendor, the other had a location header and Realex didn't have it in their HTTP response so I was wondering if that could be the case when using an Iframe in the Peoplesoft page. Or perhaps be something I am missing related to the iFrame behaviour?. That is why I posted this question. Actually looking for developers within Peoplesoft with a similar issue.
Thank you.

Comment: I am a ps developer. From my experience google has some limitations when within an iframe on psoft applications, but its a limitation on their end... log an SR with Oracle to check if the HTTP response needs to have something specific

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought the same but made a test with a different vendor and it worked fine so.. how could that actually work with a different vendor (a sister company)? so it is not a PS issue in my opinion.

Comment: It can be a limitation either on PS or in the vendors system.... I would log an SR on MOS to make sure thats no a PS limitation

Comment: I will do thanks for your comments